# How do I use the sysconf() function in C++ to find the following information?

Tags: c++

How do I find the max size of argv[], envp[], and the input line of my system?
I'm using sysconf() function.
Does sysconf(_SC_ARGMAX) give me the max size of argv[]? What about the other two?

Comment: Did you read `man 3 sysconf`?

Comment: by "input line" do you mean a line of text that can be given to a program? I believe there is no limit, `while (getchar()!= '\n');` will run forever if you keep holding the 'a' key on the keyboard or some such. After some point the input buffer of the C runtime library will be full, but it doesn't stop the line from being longer - it just means you can't go back and edit the characters that the program has already received after the buffer filled up and got handed to the program.

Answer (score -1):

From [SYSCONF(3)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/sysconf.3.html)

> **POSIX.1 Variables**
>   **ARG_MAX - _SC_ARG_MAX**
>   The maximum length of the arguments to the exec(3) family of functions. Must not be less than _POSIX_ARG_MAX (4096).
>
> **POSIX.2 Variables**
>   **LINE_MAX - _SC_LINE_MAX**
>   The maximum length of a utility's input line length, either from
>                 standard input or from a file.  This includes length for a trailing
>                 newline.
>
> **BUGS**
>   It is difficult to use ARG_MAX because it is not specified how much of the argument space for exec(3) is consumed by the user's environment variables.